# Android Login Screens switch

Tags: java, android-studio, switch-statement, screen, login-page

ANDROID STUDIO LOGIN SWICTH TO MAIN ACTIVITY

This is the error it shows me

Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.company.appname/com.company.appname.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while Launching activity

Am working on a social app and am trying to switch the screen to a login screen as soon as I enter the app but it keeps crashing on the emulator showing  errors.`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Goto logcat and select error in drop down menu and see why yohr app is crashing.
If you want  more explanation then please upload your work and logcat error So we can see what actual problem occur.

Comment: It is showing me android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER error

Comment: By this I can only understand that you are facing problem in line where you create an Intent to go back to your phone apps category .

Comment: If you want any solution then please upload your work